# Failed installation prevents further installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, live-cd

I was in the process of installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop when the screen timed out. Moving the mouse and using the keyboard would not bring back the screen, and after a couple hours I was forced to power cycle the laptop after I was unable to resume.

When I attempt to boot off the liveCD again to again attempt installation I get an error message that it is unable to find /BOOT/EFI/mmx64.efi and the laptop shuts off immediately afterwards; however I am able to boot to windows 10 with the DVD removed. After looking online for a solution and playing around with the EFI partition I have not progressed any further than I was before. Every solution I have found online assumes that either the user can boot Ubuntu or is able to boot off the liveCD, which I can do neither. Does anyone have any idea what the way ahead is to be able to install ubuntu?

I am running a MSI GT72S, and I am attempting to dual-boot with Windows 10.

Comment: If this helps, I scrubbed the EFI partition to just leave windows; however I still have a BBS priority option for Ubuntu. Is there somewhere else on the hard drive I need to look? I'm assuming if I can remove all traces of the previous install from the hard drive I can try to re-install and have it proceed as if nothing happened previously.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated the problem on the ubuntu forums at [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408929). Long story short I was unable to get 18.10 to work but the 18.04 LTS image threw the same error but let me proceed with the installation. This would be my recommendation for anyone with the same problem.